# Index out of range (-1) when I click on any item in the TListBox

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe8

The `TListBox` called `lboMtrlList` is populated with records from the database. The data displays properly when I run the application. When I click on any item in the list,  shows the error:

> Index out of range (-1)

despite the list not being empty.

Here's the code for populating the `lboMtrlList`:

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
  con.LoginPrompt := false;
  con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=C:\Users\katiee\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\ProgramDatabase;');
  query.Connection := con;
  performQuery;

  query.SQL.Text :=
  'SELECT [Material Description] FROM MtrlDatabase ORDER BY MtrlID';
 try
  query.Open;
  lboMtrlList.Items.Clear;
  while not query.EOF do
   begin
    lboMtrlList.Items.Add(query.Fields[0].AsString);
    query.Next;
   end;
  finally
   query.Close;
 end;
 //ledtDesc.Height :=  81;
 //ledtNotes.Height :=  51;
 end;
```

I want to be able to double click on an item in the `lboMtrlList` and move it to another `TListBox` called `lboSelectedMtrl`. Here's the code:

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.lboMtrlListDblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  lboMtrlList.Items.Add(lboSelectedMtrl.Items.Strings[lboSelectedMtrl.ItemIndex]);
 end;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have any other event on listbox? Try to use: `lboMtrlList.Items.Add(lboSelectedMtrl.Items[lboSelectedMtrl.ItemIndex]);`

Comment: 1) You don't need `Strings`, as it's a default property of `Items`. Use just `lboSelectedMtrl.Items[lboSelectedMtrl.ItemIndex]`. 2) You should never assume that the `ItemIndex` is valid. Always test first: `if lboSelectedMtrl.ItemIndex <> -1 then`. What happens if there are no items in the listbox and it's double-clicked? 3) Can you reproduce this in a simple test app that does not use the query to populate the listbox? If so, [edit] your post to use that code instead. If not, then do a closer inspection to see if your query returns any rows; if it doesn't, you have zero items in the listbox.

Comment: 4) The OnDoubleClick event is only fired when the control is **double-clicked** (as the name would suggest), so if you're getting the exception when the item is clicked (as in once and not a double-click), the problem is not in the code you've posted here; it would be in the `OnClick` event instead, or in an `OnChange` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to be able to double click on an item in the `lboMtrlList` and move it to another `TListBox` called `lboSelectedMtrl`.

Your code is doing the opposite of that.  It is trying to move an item from `lboSelectedMtrl` to `lboMtrlList`.  You are getting the bounds error because there is no item selected in `lboSelectedMtrl` (`lboSelectedMtrl.ItemIndex` is -1).

Swap the ListBox variables, and add some error checking:

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.lboMtrlListDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Idx := lboMtrlList.ItemIndex;
  if Idx <> -1 then
    lboSelectedMtrl.Items.Add(lboMtrlList.Items.Strings[Idx]);
end;
```

Comment: You're totally right, I've swapped them and it working exactly like I wanted. Quite embarrassing, I didn't even notice that it's the wrong way around. Thanks.